# java debugger - shortcut keys

Tags: java, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, jdb

**Summary**:  Need jdb shortcut key to terminate a hanging program

***Specifics:***
I am using the jdb from the command line.  I continue to get a "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".  This hangs up the jdb.  I want the keyboard shortcut key which will exit the program.  Currently, I have to close the command prompt to exit.  This causes me extra effort.  Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used this software before, but the common way to quit a program is either with Ctrl+C or q. Have you tried both of those already?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll This method works now.  Did not work yesterday.  Maybe alittle buggy.  Thanks for your resolution.